# Swift Date function do not work as Expected

Tags: swift, swiftdate

I am trying to find out the difference between two date in seconds using Swift 4.1. This is the code I use,

```
func getDurationInSeconds(date1 :Date) -> Int{
    guard let durationInSeconds = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: Date(), to: date1).second else {
            return 0
    }
    return durationInSeconds
}
```

Function to generate date1 from 2018-10-09T18:19:00Z

```
func dateFromString(stringDate:String) -> Date? {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale?
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDate)
        return date
    }
```

The Date is always returning back an hour less than my current device time, so the calculation is not working as expected. If my current device time is 16:34 the Date() function returns it back as 15:34.

I have seen that Date() is returning back the time in UTC not based on my timezone.

At the moment if I pass in a Date **09/10/2018 14:25:00** and the current device time is **09/10/2018 14:20:00**. I am expecting this function to return a value **300 which is 60 * 5 minute difference between two dates**.

But I am getting back a value of **3900** which is because the date function returns the date as

> 09/10/2018 13:20:00 instead of 14:20

. So the duration will be 1 hour +  the 300 second difference.

Including a sample output from Xcode console, my device time when I executed this code was **2018-10-09 17:56:28.565423**

```
(lldb) po date1
▿ 2018-10-09 17:59:00 +0000
  - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 560800740.0

(lldb) po durationInSeconds
3731

(lldb) po Date()
▿ 2018-10-09 16:57:04 +0000
  - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 560797024.35021996

(lldb)
```

But I cant find a proper way to find the correct duration between two times based on my current time zone. How can I do it?

Comment: `Date() as Date` is pointless

Comment: @rmaddy there is no issue with date one, the value of Date() is off by an hour. Please see my console outputs. date1 is hard coded now and its fine. I have issue only with the output of Date() functionality of Swift.

Comment: @EasyCoder What you are looking for is `return date1.timeIntervalSinceNow` note that this will return a Double if you want an integer `return Int(date1.timeIntervalSinceNow)`

Comment: @EasyCoder The value of `Date()` is probably not off by an hour. The problems are probably that you don't understand how `Date` works, and therefore you have probably not properly handled time zones while constructing `date1`. You think `date1` is correct because you don't understand how `Date` interacts with time zones, but in fact it is `date1` that is off by an hour.

Comment: @robmayoff When I use PO Date() the value I get in my console is off by an hour. I have shown that  in my example .

Comment: Let me guess. You are in a time zone that is 1 hour ahead of UTC.

Comment: When you see `2018-10-09 16:57:04 +0000` printed in the console, do you know what the `+0000` part means?

Comment: Yes thats correct!! But How will i get the correct time based on my timezone as Date?

Comment: Please, **please** read [the `Date` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate?language=objc): “ A representation of a specific point in time, **independent of any calendar or time zone.**” (Emphasis added.) The concept of “the correct time based on my timezone as Date” is meaningless, because a `Date` is independent of time zones. The time zone only matters when converting between a `Date` and a string, or when converting between a `Date` and a `DateComponents`, and the objects that perform those conversions let you specify a time zone.

Comment: That is why @rmaddy is asking you to edit your question to include the code that creates `date1`: because you are probably not properly handling time zones when constructing `date1`.

Comment: @EasyCoder Please read http://www.maddysoft.com/articles/dates.html to better understand dates.

Comment: @rmaddy & rob. Thanks. I got your point now, I think i am converting date1 wrongly. Added that function to original question.

Comment: What do you do with the result of `dateFromString` before calling `getDurationInSeconds` or evening printing `date1`? You must be doing something with that value to cause the 1 hour difference.

Comment: How do you get `stringDate` passed to `dateFromString(stringDate:)` ? The letter `Z` in `2018-10-09T18:19:00Z` represents UTC, not your local time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the *Date()* returning wrong time. *Date()* always returns the current time, which is not really based on your (any other) local timezone.

The problem seems to be with the **dateFormatter** that you are using to generate the **Date** object from the date string.

Please try using the following lines of code:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

// Not necessary as the dateFormatter would take the device's timeZone to be the default.
dateFormatter.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
```

instead of:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
```

The problem with the latter is that, you are specifying '**Z**' to be the zero-offset time zone (UTC). So, the difference of 1 hour from UTC in your device is causing this offset.

And, while passing in the date string, please make sure that you skip the 'Z' at the end (For example, it should be like **2018-10-09T18:19:00**).

The updated code should work good for you, and return the expected difference in seconds.

Answer (score -2):

Since you are using a string that represents the current time in your time zone, try this instead:

```
func getDurationInSeconds(date1: Date) -> Int {
    return Int(-date1.timeIntervalSinceNow + TimeZone.current.daylightSavingTimeOffset(for: date1))
}
```

It uses [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1780473-timeintervalsincenow) property and [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timezone/2293268-daylightsavingtimeoffset) method.

Or if you'd like to account for the time zone difference from UTC in `dateFromString(stringDate:)`:

```
func getDurationInSeconds(date1: Date) -> Int {
    return Int(-date1.timeIntervalSinceNow)
}

func dateFromString(stringDate:String) -> Date? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDate)! //I am force-unwrapping for brevity
    let adjustedDate = date.addingTimeInterval(-TimeZone.current.daylightSavingTimeOffset(for: date))
    return adjustedDate
}
```

**Test**

I am in a UTC + 1h timezone:

```
let str = "2018-10-09T19:50:00Z"    //"2018-10-09T19:50:00Z"
let date1 = dateFromString(stringDate: str)! //"Oct 9, 2018 at 7:50 PM"
Date()         //At the time of testing this it is "Oct 9, 2018 at 7:53 PM"
getDurationInSeconds(date1: date1)  //213, which is 3 minutes and 33 seconds
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the OP's actual issue. This is just another way to write the code that is already working fine.

Comment: That's wrong. There's no need to adjust for day light saving time. There is nothing wrong with the OP's getDurationInSeconds function.

Comment: In what way is it wrong? could you elaborate? The OP wants to get the duration between a string that represents the time in its current timezone, and now.

Comment: Getting the difference between two `Date` instances does not involve any timezones. `Date` has no timezone. And throwing in day light saving time just makes no sense. There is nothing wrong with any of the code posted in the question so far. Your attempts to "fix" this particular function are not needed since it's not the issue.

Comment: @rmaddy If I understand the OP correctly, they are passing a string that is supposed to be in their timezone and not in the default UTC. Setting the timezone in `dateFromString` has no effect on the output `Date?`. Fixing the timezone difference could be done either before returning the date, or in `getDurationInSeconds`

Comment: No, the OP is passing a string in the UTC timezone. That's what the `Z` at the end of the date string means. And there's nothing to fix in `getDurationInSeconds`.

Comment: @rmaddy The OP did say the Date() function returns "*13:20:00 instead of 14:20*" (they are on UTC +1h) and that they are passing `14:20:00` and not `13:20:00` to the `dateFromString` function.

Comment: To the downvoters, please prove me wrong with a valid counterexample. *(Bear in mind that the OP is passing a string that represents the current time in their time zone)*

Comment: No, the OP is passing a string in the UTC timezone. That's what the `Z` means (as I stated earlier). Your misuse of `daylightSavingTimeOffset` has no use in converting a date string into a date. And 19:50 UTC time would be 20:50 in a UTC+1 timezone.

Comment: @rmaddy fair enough, let me reformulate: the OP *thinks* that they are passing the time in their current time zone. In a test playground, and being in UTC+1, not including the `daylightSavingTimeOffset` **does** add 3600 seconds to the result, even if `date1` and `Date()` are separated by less than 5minutes.

Comment: No, 3600 seconds are not added. The OP's original code is 100% correct as is for the input given. The problem is not with the posted code. The problem is with whatever they are doing with the date elsewhere or it is simply confusion about dates. Either way, your answer is incorrect. Your answer is incorrectly attempting to compensate for some other mistake or confusion.

Comment: @rmaddy Could you explain why using the original code, and being in UTC+1, current time is `21:32` with this code `let str = "2018-10-09T21:30:00Z"; let date1 = dateFromString(stringDate: str)!; getDurationInSeconds(date1: date1)` yields `3476`? `21:32` is 8:32 PM in UTC, that's why

Comment: The OP expects it to be less than two minutes, they *think* they are passing a time in the current time zone.